# FTPS using Vsftp woes

Tags: ftp, ftps, vsftpd, gnutls

I have some problems with Vstpd, and I don't know whether they are related or not.

One problem is that FireFTP can't get past the directory listing phase - it just stucks there forever, no error messages. Filezilla works, however it too sometimes gets stuck. In particular there are some files that just won't upload -- they too are stuck forever, sometimes a few bytes go through; here, too, no error messages server-side, and just a timeout client-side. Other clients seem totally unaffected (in particular Cyberduck on windows and Transmit on mac always worked flawlessly).

With FileZilla, the file I am attempting to upload will be created on the server with zero byte size, but nothing will be uploaded. If the file was already there, it will be emptied. I can also upload other files to the same directory, so it is not a permissions issue.

Is there any problem with my configuration? Am I using an outdated version? (It's Ubuntu 10.04). Here is vsftpd.conf. Using a self-signed cert.

**Maybe this is a Linux problem??? Using Ubuntu 12.04 as client OS.**

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
session_support=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

ssl_enable=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
```

Comment: Other people also experience this, like here: http://imadethisdesign.blogspot.it/2009/05/vsftpd-ftps-and-fireftp-dont-mix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was on the client, not on the server!

I investigated further, and I found out that the most probablle culprit is the **gnutls** version installed in the client's machine (it is Ubuntu 12.04, GnuTLS 2.12.14).

To verify this, I downloaded the windows version of FileZilla, which is statically linked to a 2.10 version, and ran it using Wine. It works!!

Digging FileZilla's bugtracker I finally fond the confirmation: http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/7837

Answer (score 0):

It is related to passive FTP or FTPS. 100%

It won't work securely for FTPS - then you will need to adjust and open higher ports manually in firewalls and set fixed range with `pasv_min_port` & `pasv_max_port` in vsftpd.conf.

For non-SSL:

http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

1. Be sure to load ip_nat_ftp (if you use NAT on THIS SERVER) and
   ip_conntrack_ftp modules
2. Use "ftp helper" in your iptables configuration for FTP:

   `-m helper --helper ftp`

In case of RHEL/Fedora/Centos you can find special string for modules in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` and add helper in rules for `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

This is for any case.

In case you are behind NAT/Firewall - it should support and track FTP connections.

Comment: Add. info: http://www.ipv4security.com/packet_flow/ftp_over_ssl.html